# RedBeanPHP relations

Tags: redbean

I cannot for the life of me get RedBeanPHP to return beans/objects for relations.

I created a person. I attached a related photo bean and added it to the person's list of photos. I saved the person. The DB correctly showed all records and relations. When I try to load the $person bean and dereference the photos list, it's always null !

```
   $person = R::dispense('person');
   $photo  = R::dispense('photo');

   $person->name="Bob";
   $photo->name="BigPic";

   $person->ownPhotos[] = $photo;
   R::store($person);

   $person = R::findOne('person', ' username = ? ', array("Bob"));
   $logger->dump("Person", $person); //It's a valid bean
   $logger->dump("Photos",$person->alias('photo')->ownPhotos); //It's null
   $logger->dump("Photos",$person->ownPhotos); //It's null
```

**Question :**
 Why are `$person->ownPhotos and $person->alias('photo')->ownPhoto` always null?

Comment: try ownPhotosList[]  you may need to flush and reconstract databese

Answer (score 1):

Try not pluralizing the bean name:

```
$person = R::dispense('person');
   $photo  = R::dispense('photo');

   $person->name="Bob";
   $photo->name="BigPic";

   $person->ownPhoto = array($photo);
   R::store($person);

   $person = R::findOne('person', ' username = ? ', array("Bob"));
   $logger->dump("Person", $person); //It's a valid bean
   $logger->dump("Photos",$person->alias('photo')->ownPhoto); //It's null
   $logger->dump("Photos",$person->ownPhoto); //It's null
```

As far as I know, there isn't a pluralizing feature yet in Redbean, but I haven't really been working with it recently.  The docs (http://www.redbeanphp.com/adding_lists) show that they aren't pluralizing either, so I would stick to that.  Make sure to check your database after queries to see if things are being inserted properly, not just checking the logs.  You should see a row created in your photo table called `person_id` if it works.